# Proguard configuration for sqlite android bindings

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-proguard

I am trying to use SQLite android bindings to have a custom encrypted SQLite DB in my android app. It all works fine and I am about to publish my app. I am trying to use ProGuard for code obfuscation and compression but does not seem to work fine with SQLite android bindings. My released app crashes on startup because it cannot find few .so files used by SQLite. I am not sure what should be the correct ProGuard rule to keep those libraries.

Right now I have added only this to my ProGuard:

```
-keep class org.sqlite.**
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually,

```
-keep class org.sqlite.** { *; }
-keep class org.sqlite.database.** { *; }
```

would do the trick.

Verify your **`mapping.txt`** for what `ProGuard` is already done, and make sure that your *models* are not got renamed. If so, you may need

```
-keep class com.your.modelspackage.**
-keepclassmembers com.your.modelspackage.** { *; }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I encounter this problem currently, I have used this following plugin with Unity for android which work very well without proguard. github.com/rizasif/sqlite-unity-plugin-example

I added the first two lines to my pro guard, but it didn't worked.

From the answer above from @Let'sRefactor, Could you explain what represent modelspackage?